# How to perform Analysis of Means (ANOM) using Python?

Tags: python, analysis-of-means

While Analysis of Means (ANOM) is available through R, SAS, JMP, and presumably other statistical platforms, I am having trouble finding an implementation in Python.

Is there a way to do ANOM in Python?  Any help would be appreciated, especially in regard to graphically displaying the ANOM results (i.e., plotting arithmetic means by category in relation to the category's upper decision limit (*UDL*) and lower decision limit (*LDL*)).

This is not a coding question as the calculation of critical values *m(α; I; ν)* (used for *UDL* & *LDL* calculation in a 1-factor unbalanced study) is a **statistical challenge**.  In particular, calculating *m(α; I; ν)* is necessary since tables in literature have gaps that need to be extrapolated when *k* > 20 or *ν* > 20.